# Is it possible to show ruby gem updates without actually updating?

Tags: rubygems

I have checked the docs, but I didn't find a way to check for gems with updates available.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I find the answer minutes later:

```
gem outdated
```